# Is it possible to short on Bitfinex using a SELL-STOP, then BUY-STOP and BUY-LIMIT at the same time?

Tags: bitfinex, margin

I would like to know if it's possible to do this short order without having to manually add the stop loss after it's opened.

Say the price is currently $300, and if it hits $280 I know it will probably drop, so I want to margin sell-stop at $280 to sell at this level.

I want to buy them back at $250, so I put in a margin buy-limit at $250 to buy them back at that level.

That all works okay and I can add those orders at the same time. But is it possible to add a stop loss to my short order, to sell if the price goes back up to $290? This would be a margin buy-stop order at $290 I believe, but if I add that to my orders list, it would be executed immediately as the price is $300 and that would ruin the trade.

Is it possible to do this, essentially saying "only execute this order if this other order has been executed"? Or is this the kind of stuff that trading bots do?

Thanks

Comment: OCO orders? Not sure but this would be an OCO and may help guide your search for the answer